# Display raw html - Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am looking to display the raw HTML code (example.component.html) below 'example works!'. The page should display the following:

```
example works!    
<p>   
  example works!
</p>
```

I can find various resources showing how this can be done using AngularJS but not Angular 6.

I have tried to use [innerHTML] but this didn't work.

---

```
<p>
  example works!
</p>
```

**example.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'rt-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css']
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <rt-example></rt-example>
</div>
```

> **OUTPUT** . . [link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyR7A.jpg)

Comment: @ritaj at the moment the text 'example works!' is displayed but I would like to add the raw html code below it. 
<p>
  example works!
</p>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 Output Complete HTML Syntax code in HTML as raw text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46911008/angular-4-output-complete-html-syntax-code-in-html-as-raw-text)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `ViewContainerRef` to get the nativeElement, and get its innerHTML.

Just a warning : this won't be your HTML code, but the compiled code.

Here is an example : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cwsqy8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
export class AppComponent  {
  htmlContent: string;
  constructor(private view: ViewContainerRef) {
    setTimeout(() => this.htmlContent = (view.element.nativeElement as HTMLElement).innerHTML);
  }
}
```

**EDIT** If you want the uncompiled code, you should use this notation : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p5zpts?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as template from "./app.component.html";


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  htmlContent: string = template.default;
  constructor(private view: ViewContainerRef) {
  }
}
```

But I suggest you use the latest versions of typescript & Angular, since I'm not sure when it has been introduced.

Comment: that's really useful, thanks but I'm looking for the HTML code rather than the compiled code.

Comment: I have edited the code and added the example component https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jgelqd but I think I have made an error. The HTML code at the bottom isn't right.

Comment: I have added an image link in the question for clarity to give a better idea of what I'm looking for.... I would like the HTML code at the bottom to resemble that of the code in example.component.html without the <div class="markup">{{ htmlContent }}</div> . Is this possible?

Comment: No it's not. For that, you'll need two components. You can't just pick what you like in a template. If you want to do that, simply rewrite your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Get a reference pointing to that component using ViewChild, like

```
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild(ExampleComponent, { read: ElementRef }) exampleComponent;
}
```

Then you can access its HTML with `nativeElement.innerHTML`.

So you could change your `app.component.html` to this:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <rt-example></rt-example>
</div>

{{exampleComponent.nativeElement.innerHTML}}
```

Comment: Not wrong, but `ViewContainerRef` allows him to get directly the host component (the `<my-app>` tag directly)

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, attribute binding to innerHTML works.

```
<div [innerHTML]="myHtml"></div>
```

Answer (score -3):

In HTML, you need to use [entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) to show the reserved characters.

```
<p>example works!</p>

<code>&lt;p&gt;example works!&lt;/p&gt;</code>
```

**For example:**

`&amp;` is equivalent to `&`

`&lt;` is equivalent to `<`

`&gt;` is equivalent to `>`

**However solution using angular would be:**

**Component:**

```
export class SomeComponent  {
  code :string = `<p>example</p>`
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<code>{{this.code}}</code>
```

**OR Use InnerText instead of InnerHTML**

```
<p [innerText]="code"></p>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5cpmcr

Comment: @rf2018 tag `<code>` is optional. You can use other tags too.