# Show HTML string as plain text in Angular

Tags: angular, quill, ngx-quill

I'm developing a blog using Angular. There I want to show HTML string retrieved from the database as plain text (for listing each blog post's preview). The HTML rich-text was generated using `ngx-quill`.

I can able to render the rich text by using the code `<quill-view [content]="post.content"></quill-view>`. But I need to render the same content as plain text.

How can I do this in an `ngx-quill` / Angular way. Please help!
I prefer not to go for fetching `DOMElement.text()` method using *JavaScript*.

Comment: Have you looked/tried out https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation?

Comment: Does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/46911008/1160794

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't know about quill..

so may be there will be another good solution

i think you can solve this problem  with pipe something like this

```js
@Pipe({ name: 'truncateHtml' })
export class TruncateHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform{

    constructor() { }

    transform(text: string ) {

        if (!text) {
            return text;
        }

        let without_html = text.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, ' ');
        
        return without_html;
    }

}
```

if you don't wanna use in template

just return that value and use it

i hope it helps

Comment: this solution worked for me. But after this pipe operation I there was some additional spaces and line breaks. To remove that I have added the below regex.

.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'') // To replace more than one spaces
.replace(/&nbsp;/gi," ") // To replace HTML encoded character (here &nbsp;)
.replace(/(?:(?:\r\n|\r|\n)\s*){2,}/gim, "\n\n") // to replace multiple new lines

Adding these expressions to the pipe worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `innerHTML` like this

```
<div [innerHTML]="blogPost"></div>
```

I used it before also with Quill

Comment: The variable "blogPost" has an HTML string. you solution will show the contents as it is. I need to show it as a plain text. So no HTML tags will be available in the string "blogPost".

Comment: This will render the HTML string. But I needed to render it as only plain text. The above answer worked for me, there it will strip out all the HTML tags to that I can get plain text.

Comment: The variable "blogPost" as an HTML string. My requirement is to remove those HTML tags to that I can show the contents as plain text. But using the solution that you have mentioned, it will render the text as rich-text. The above answer(using pipe stripping out the HTML tags to get a plain text) is the working solution for me.